# std::map works on Windows 32bit but crashes on 64bit

Tags: c++, string, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a string map with two entries in it:
`"Chicago"--> ChicagoObj`   and `"NewYork"-->NewYorkObj`, where `ChicagoObj` and `NewYorkObj` are pointers to objects of `MyClass`.

The following code compiles and runs fine in 32bit, it compiles in 64bit, but always crashes in 64bit after print out Chicago entry. Any help is appreciated!

```
typedef std::map<std::string, MyClass*> MyStringMap;
MyStringMap my_map;

std::string key1="Chicago";
MyClass *ChicagoObj = new MyClass;
my_map[key1] = ChicagoObj;

std::string key2="NewYork";
MyClass *NewYorkObj = new MyClass;
my_map[key2] = NewYorkObj ;

MyStringMap::iterator iObjMap = my_map.begin();

while (iObjMap != my_map.end())
{
    std::string key = iObjMap->first;

    std::cout<<"name of the key in the map: " << key <<std::endl;
    iObjMap++;
}
```

Comment: I see mixed use of "string" and "std::string", I assume a typo, else it is possible "string" might not really be a "std::string" at all.

Comment: You should not be using `C`-style casts with object types like `std::string`, even if in this case it looks harmless.

Comment: Does this code actually compile? It seems to be missing a few things, for example, what is "my_map"?

Comment: Why do you need a local variable for the key? Why the C-style cast? Why not just `iObjMap->first.c_str()`?

Comment: First, get rid of the casts -- they shouldn't be needed, and may be covering up the problem. Second, get rid of `printf`, it's not typesafe. You also haven't shown the definitions of `MyClass` or `my_map`, which may well matter here.

Comment: What does 32-bit/64-bit have to do with anything?  Are you saying it works in 32-bit but crashes in 64-bit?  Or are you saying it doesn't work in either?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your testcase is missing, at least, `int main()`. Please create a **short**, **complete** testcase that demonstrates your problem. See http://sscce.org for more information.

Comment: There's a local copy, and no indication that the `iterator` itself is `const` (it's not forced to be here).  Also, the code (with a simple `MyClass` replacement and some formatting) does compile and run in x86 and x64 with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @Chad - "the code ... does compile and run". That's all the more reason why we should ask him for the code that *doesn't* run. He posted code that works; presumably he hasn't yet posted the code that  fails.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's reply. I have used std::string for defining key1 and key2, added declaration of my_map, used stream instead of printf, and clarified the different behavior in 32bit and 64bit.

Comment: @Jerry: that code cannot compile, there is no such thing as `std::out`. Please post _the actual code that fails_. (Or better, a real, short, complete example that exhibits the same problem.)

Comment: Can you post a failing test case that demonstrates the problem with your code?

Comment: What type of "crash" are you having?

Comment: @josehpthomas: The crash is due to invalid memory access

Comment: @Jerry: What compiler are you using? I am having no issues with it compiling. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the latest code compiled and are not running a program with a previous bug? I have compiled your code in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 64 and there are no problems.

There is a compiling error in your code though, `std::out` should be `std::cout`. Other than that though, there is not even a warning from /Wall.

Comment: "There is not even a warning from /Wall."  That cannot be true.  The Standard Library headers (like `<map>`) will not compile cleanly with /Wall.  Do you mean /W4?

Answer (score 0):

Since you apparently won't post a complete, compilable piece of code to demonstrate the problem, here's a short demonstration of how it can work:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

class City {
    unsigned int population;
    // probably more stuff here, but this should be enough for now.
public:
    City(int pop=0) : population(pop) {}

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, City const &c) {
        return os << c.population;
    }

};


std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, 
                         std::pair<std::string, City> const &d) 
{
    return os << d.first << ": " << d.second;
}

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, City> cities;
    typedef std::pair<std::string, City> ct;

    cities["Chicago"] = City(3456789);
    cities["New York"] = City(8765432);

    std::copy(cities.begin(), cities.end(), 
        std::ostream_iterator<ct>(std::cout, "\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

I've compiled and tested this on 64-bit Windows, and it seems to work just fine. It would appear (at least to me) that `map` works on 64-bit Windows without a problem. Exactly what you've done that's breaking is hard to guess, but it may be easier to extend working code to do what you want, than figure out what's broken in code that doesn't work.